# Text file as data source in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I need to use text files as data source in SSRS. I tried accessing this with ‘OLEDB provider for Microsoft directory services’ connection. But I could not. The query is given below.

Also let me know how to query the data

Comment: Which answer worked for you?

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is old, but as it came up in my search results this may help other people.

There are two 'sort of' workarounds for this.  See the following:
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=130650

So basically you should use OLEDB as the data source, then in the connection string type:

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=xxxx;Extended Properties="text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"

Then make sure your file is saved in .txt format, with comma delimiters.  Where I've put xxxx you need to put the FOLDER directory - so C:\Temp - don't go down to the individual file level, just the folder it's in.

In the query you write for the dataset, you specify the file name as though it were a table - essentially your folder is your database, and the files in it are tables.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have had great success creating linked servers in SQL to link to disparate text files for creating SSRS reports. Below is sample SQL to link to your txt files:

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', @datasrc=N'', @provstr=N'text'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'YourLinkedServerName',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL

Answer (score 2):

I simply used BULK INSERT command to load the flat file into a temporary table in SSRS, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #FlatFile
(
    Field1 int,
    Field2 varchar(10),
    Field3 varchar(15),
    Field4 varchar(20),
    Field5 varchar(50)
)

BEGIN TRY
BULK INSERT #FlatFile
   FROM 'C:\My_Path\My_File.txt'
   WITH   
      (  
         FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t',   -- TAB delimited
         ROWTERMINATOR ='\n',     -- or '0x0a' (whatever works)
         FIRSTROW = 2,            -- has 1 header row
         ERRORFILE = 'C:\My_Path\My_Error_File.txt',
         TABLOCK
      );  
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  -- do nothing (prevent the query from aborting on errors...)
END CATCH

SELECT * FROM #FlatFile
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can

[Data Sources Supported by Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159219%28SQL.90%29.aspx). In the table, your only chance would be "Generic ODBC data source", however a text file is not ODBC compliant AFAIK. No types, no structure etc.

Why not just display the text files? It seems a bit strange to query text files to bloat them into formatted HTML...

Comment: They could be CSV or tab-delimited text files, which would be rather ugly to display, especially if you wanted aggregates or other SQL functions applied.

Comment: @Eric: true, but what structure could you aggregate on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not of the mind that you can, but a workaround for this, if your text files are CSVs or the like, is to create an SSIS package which brings that data into a table in SQL Server, which you can then query like there's no tomorrow. SSIS does Flat File Sources with ease.

You can even automate this by right clicking the database in SSMS, doing Tasks->Import Data. Walk through the wizard, and you can then save off the package at the end.